# Can't install devise on rails 4 on MinGW

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mingw

I use rails on Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1 (synchronization via dropbox).
I've written `gem 'device'` and run:

> bundle install

in Windows and Ubuntu, in both bundle answers:

> Could not find gem 'device (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.

How can I install devise?

Comment: The error is telling you.  You are trying to install a gem named "device" but you are asking about devise.  Change the name to devise, or alternatively, if you want to install your gem, you have to tell it where it is.  Perhaps by path, or push it to the rubygems server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you typed

```
gem 'device'
```

instead of

```
gem 'devise'
```